# Find all prime number solutions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

Find all prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p^{q+1} + q^{p+1}$ is a perfect square.

Number theory problems like these are always difficult for me. So please insert the topics under which this problem has been asked and also I welcome your solution.

Comment: Which contest was it? Seems much too easy to be an olympiad problem.

Comment: The only solution is $p=q=2$.

Comment: @almagest This is form a Dutch IMO selection test.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation in module $4$.
Every  odd number($n$) is always: $$n\equiv \pm 1\pmod 4$$ therefore this expression is:$$p^{q+1} + q^{p+1}\equiv \pm1^{q+1} \pm 1^{p+1}\equiv 1+1\equiv 2 \pmod 4$$ But the quadratic residue mod $4$ are $0$ and $1$. Therefore contradiction. From here $p$ or $q$ or both must be equal $2$. You can control easily  that there is a only solution for $p=q=2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose $p$ is odd and it is a perfect square. Then $$p^{q+1}+q^{p+1}=a^2,$$

$$p^{q+1}=a^2-q^{p+1}$$

$$p^{q+1}= \left(a-q^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\right)\left(a+q^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\right)$$

So then both $\left(a-q^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\right)$ and $\left(a+q^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\right)$ must be powers of $p$.

Comment: Don't forget p=q=2.